# How to implement a distributed registry using JMS?

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, jms

Just to get the context clear:

I've implemented a monitoring application under Java EE (using GlassFish as application server), which is accessible by a REST-service to get different information. One of the retrievable information should be *best server currently available* (e.g. in terms of free resources [CPU, RAM, storage,...]).

Therefor I would like to link all servers, where my application is deployed, in the form of a distributed registry via JMS. The purpose is, that a server dynamically gonna be part of that registry after deployment of the application. In the end, if for example the former best server is under heavy load, a message is sent to the others to inform about his current state (and update the registry).

What is the most nifty way to make the servers known to each other after deployment of the application? (fixed, stand-alone registry, where they have to register?)

How many JMS providers are feasible? 
Is it possible to set-up multiple/all (application)-servers as provider? 
Is there a way to set-up a server as provider at runtime?

Comment: Not sure I understand your idea correctly, but I think you should be looking at a standalone broker (what they call JMS Service Type REMOTE in Glassfish) and use a Topic. Topics can have multiple producers, also producers that join later on, and all consumers currently attached to the topic will receive all messages published to the topic. Can you tell me what you define as a "provider"?

Comment: @fvu In my view a provider is the application server which provides the broker functionality (Open MQ) and transmits the messages (from/to producer/consumer). Did I misunderstand it? I want the broker to be replaceable at runtime to avoid a single point of failure.

Comment: [OpenMQ used to support HA setups](https://mq.java.net/OpenMQ_MySQLCluster_Setup_Guide.html), maybe it still does. On the other hand, over many years of use it's proven rock-solid here, that's why I stopped worrying about HA :) But in that case that's definitely something you could do, one central broker with a number of GF instances using it (as a remote broker). So, my proposal remains valid :)

Comment: @fvu Thanks a lot. Just to get it straight (since I am newcomer): you would recommend using only one remote broker (a server which is running GlassFish with OpenMQ) and transmit all messages from/to multiple producers/consumers via this broker (using publish-subscribe model)? There is one thing left I would like to know about. I'm going to edit my question for this, since it's gonna take a while and I got to go now. Would appreciate your further expertise. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend indeed to build all your workers around one broker, or if you really think it's necessary, an OpenMQ broker configured for high availability. Unless you expect very high traffic to be produced by other JMS dependent applications running on the servers, such a scenario should be entirely sufficient, and a lot easier to set up. Now, by default the OpenMQ broker that comes with Glassfish will start inside the JVM that also hosts the GF instance, but that can easily be changed. Read more about the three supported running modes [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/gipbg.html#giplw). In so-called remote mode, the JMS broker runs in its own JVM and it's your responsability to stop and start it, ideally before the first worker starts.

There are plenty of configuration possibilities there, I recommend you set up a test environment and test both its performance and behavior in less than ideal circumstances (eg, broker dying for whatever reason) to understand what you can expect from the system.

Last but not least, it's relatively easy to integrate other JMS brokers in Glassfish (like shown [here with ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/integrating-apache-activemq-with-glassfish.html) but my experience has been that OpenMQ is a reliable, mature, well documented product, and thus it should be your first choice.

Comment: Sorry, very busy week. I read through the docu and especially the JMX part since I would like to set up the whole JMS functionality programmatically at runtime. Do you have experience with the programmatic configuration of these things via JMX? Let's say I deploy my application at a specific server and want this server to be my (remote) broker. Is it possible to perform all necessary configuration steps (create a ConnectionFactory, Destination) solely within my application, instead of using the administration console or whatever?

Comment: Additionally it's still not 100% clear to me which configuration steps I have to perform on my remote broker and which on my workers (producers/consumers). Sorry for the possibly trivial questions, but the stuff is a bit blurry to me. Thanks in advance.